# pulling data from different sources and store in mongodb

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb

I am trying to pull data from multiple sources for a cryptocurrency app, so it will be a market price source and 2 metrics sources (cryptoquant and glassnode). The thing is, market price data has a fixed schema (ohlcv ...), but in cryptoquant, each feature, for example, if you choose "reserve", the result in application/json format returns `reserve` and `reserve_usd` value, while you choose netflow, it only has `netflow_total`.

I am trying to have a schema like

```js
//ohlcv schema    
const OHLCVModelSchema = new Schema({
    timestamp: String,
    open: Number,
    high: Number,
    low: Number,
    close: Number,
    volume: Number,
})

// cryptoquant schema
const CQSchema = new Schema({
    status: {
        code: Number,
        message: String,
    },
    result: {
        window: String,
        data: [
            {
                date: String,
                xxxx: Number,
                xxxx: Number,
            }
        ]
    }
})
```

xxx is different for different features, how can I just dump everything (mainly the data portion) into a database like MongoDB without writing out the schema explicitly for every feature?

Comment: In general, MongoDB's _document model_ allows storing documents with different structure within a same collection. It looks like you are using Mongoose ODM for your schema definitions.

Comment: thanks, I am just wondering if I can dump the whole application/json request I got into a database without fitting into a schema? Is it possible?

Comment: You can try [mongoimport](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongoimport/) command line tool to import data from JSON or CSV files.